# Javascript invalid date in FF, ok in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, firefox, date-formatting

In Javascript, the following date is coming up invalid for Firefox.  It is valid Chrome.  I really want to keep the format because of the 3 digit month and timezone inclusion.  How can i get this to be valid in Firefox?

```
var d = new Date("16-Jan-2014 10:56:24 am PST");
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Changing the - to a / makes it valid, but neither is valid in IE.

Comment: i have updated the anser use space instead '/' or '-' good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var d = new Date("16 Jan 2014 10:56:24 am PST");
console.log(d);
```

Tested and varified in 
1) IE
2) Chrome
3) Firefox

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78E4Q/2/)

[image]

good luck!

Comment: Just one more request, yes that worked.  But not in IE.

Comment: i have updated the answer... this works in IE as well - Tested and verified.